# Gromov's quick "proof" of Lefchetz Hyperplane Theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I'd say I'm fairly comfortable with standard proofs of the Lefschetz Hyperplane theorem (e.g. lefschetz pencils, morse theory, etc.). However, in the first chapter of Gromov's *Partial Differential Relations*, the author provides the following proof sketch (paraphrased):

> Begin as usual with an embedding of a Stein manifold $V$ in $\mathbb{C^n}$ and a generic point $ \in \mathbb{C^n}$, such that the distance function $d$ is morse. Through any critical point $x$ find a holomorphically-embedded Riemann surface $X$ with tangent plane spanning $(v,Jv)$ for arbitrary vector $v$ at $x$. Restricting $d$ to $X$ we see, by "Louville's theorem", that $d$ does not attain a local minimum, and thus, since $v$ was arbitrary, the index of $d$ at $x$ is at most $\dim V$.

It seems to me that by invoking "louville's theorem" (which I assume refers to the classical theorem of basic complex analysis or a similar maximum principle) Gromov is just being handwavy, and to complete the proof rigorously one would just proceed similarly to what one does in, say, Milnor's Morse theory text. Moreover, it doesn't seem like this proof could be fixed as written: it suffers from a uncomfortable relationship with symmetry, and any argument proceeding from "Louville's theorem", or any similarly fundemental principle, should not be able to distinguish minima from maxima, leading us to conclude that Stein manifolds have the homotopy type of a ball, a clear absurdity.

However, I have found in the past that Gromov's less-than-rigorous moments signal interesting ideas,and his "errors" often come from novel insights, often in non-obvious ways. Is this the case here? Or is the argument he sketches truly erroneous?

Comment: The embedding is usually chosen proper, such that the distance function restricts to a proper Morse function on V with compact sublevel-sets. This property is not preserved by replacing d by -d.

Comment: @user_1789 Oh, of course we can't just multiply by minus one and expect Morse theory to yield the result we want. My statement concerned Gromov's application of "Louville's theorem", which unless he is referring to another theorem of Louville that I am not aware of, says that holomorphic mappings from our surface into $\mathbb{C}$ do not possess either local maxima or local minimum (as one would know from any intro course in complex analysis).Of course, symmetry is not the only reason this doesn't work as written: the distance function certainly isn't holomorphic; it is even real-valued.

Comment: @user_1789 (continuing) However, it seems plausible that a similar broad maximum principle could suffice; I feel like Gromov might be hinting at something like that, since the argument makes so little sense the way that I'm reading it. If so, I would suspect the same sort of symmetry problem to arise, which is why I have my doubts. That being said, Gromov might just have better things to do than to prove such a well-known theorem, and put that argument there as a short indication of the proof.  I can't tell as is.

Comment: The nonexistence of local maxima of $d$ on $X$ (local minima can definitely occur) follows from the fact that the function $d^2$ is (strictly) plurisubharmonic on $\mathbb{C}^n$: As (the sum of squares of) absolute values of holomorphic functions, its restriction to any Riemann surface is (strictly) subharmonic. Gromov may have referred to a variation of the following statement as "Liouville's theorem": A (strictly) subharmonic function does not have any local maxima (in the interior of a domain).